# Should I Trust a Certificate

Tags: wifi, security, internet, certificate

Basically, my school is apparently having a network 'update' and are telling us to go to keychain access and trust a certificate. This is what they sent us.[image]
[image]
[image]
Exactly what will happen if I do this any? Do you have any recommendations for what I should do?

Comment: Are you a student or a member of staff? Is this your personal computer or a device supplied by the school?

Comment: Personal Computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trusting a certificate gives the owner of that certificate the ability to limit security warnings when performing some tasks. These tasks include installing new software, and intercepting & proxying secure connections.

Whether you should follow the request to trust the certificate depends on who owns the computer.

See [Should I let my child's school have access to my kid's personal laptop?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/192535/should-i-let-my-childs-school-have-access-to-my-kids-personal-laptop) for a related question over on the Information Security site.

### School Device

If the computer is supplied by the school and the school want you to install their trusted certificate, then you should do so.

### Personal Device

If this computer is yours, I would not trust their certificate. Adding an **always trusted** certificate is significant step and should rarely be needed on a personal device.

## Minimum Trust

Note the sub-options in step 5:

[image: Keychain certificate trust]

You can choose to trust the certificate only for certain functions. If the certificate is intended to allow locally developed and signed software to run, then only **Code Signing** should be required. Maybe **X.509 Basic Policy** also.

I would avoid trusting **Secure Sockets Layers (SSL)** until it is proven essential. This trust would allow the school to intercept previously secure Internet connections.

You could incrementally trust/distrust parts the certificate until you found the minimum set of trust required.

Comment: I’d second this. But I believe the school is deploying some internal application and has saved on getting a certificate from a trusted third party. The app has created its own certificate and hence require trusting.

Comment: I do not want to assume the reason why. We do not know the owner of the device or the intent of the certificate.

Comment: I also found it suspicious as they gave us only a week to do it

Comment: Would SSL stop VPNs from working at school?

Comment: Your VPN would continue to work. However, your VPN software would *always trust* the school's certificate for SSL/TLS and thus the school can undermine the security of connections via the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I’d say no. This is an intermediate CA (and below that a Root CA). This enables the owner of that CA to man in the middle your connections. There is no reason to accept such a CA unless there is a large volume of internal applications. The general application of a CA like that is for SSL man in the middle boxes that do traffic inspection — often badly configured.

Comment: Is it possible that they are trying to look for hackers on the network

Comment: Possible, this would be a crappy way to try to do that